# How facebook Share box identify entered link and show thumbnails and text of that link

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share

How facebook identify the entered hyperlink and get data from that link. it shows thumbnails, text, pictures, etc. Does facebook using any javascript for framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open graph protocol (OGP)](http://opg.me) is what helps Facebook get specific data from URL i.e. Web page title, site name, description ... etc
To install OGP on your site (page)

Add: `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` into `<html>` tag

And:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{Title}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="{site_type}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{page_URL}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{Thumbnail}" />
```

between `<head>` tags.

Those above are basic meta properties You can read more about it on [OGP](http://opg.me)